# Getting Infinite Scroll and link_to_next_page working with Kaminari on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript, infinite-scroll, kaminari

I've got infinite scroll working via Kaminari per the [wiki](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery) in a rails 3.2 app, and wanted to add a "more" button.

The link_to_next_page helper is great, but what's the best way to share page number across the two approaches?

Right now, everything works except that loading the second page of data via the button doesn't increment the page variable I'm using in the javascript to track which page to load for infinite scroll.

What's the best approach to sharing state across the two methods?

Other relevant information:

- each page is rendering a partial with a bunch of `li`s and appending it to a `ul`
- the 'more' button is rerendered on each ajax request

Comment: Hey, Did you found any solution for the "Load More Button" with kaminari Infinite Scrolling, i have similar issue here.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being what I was trying to initially, but my images were loading slowly, blocking the javascript from running. Now I keep the button disabled.